# Connecting Android tablet as testing device

Tags: adb, tablet, usb-debugging, usb-drivers

I have a problem related to connectivity between my desktop (Windows) and tablet (Android 4.1). I bought a new device (Colorovo City Tab Vision 7) and now I want to use it for testing of my applications, because emulation of android is very slow on my computer, although I forced it to create snapshot every run.
I have downloaded SDK with Google drivers and also some unofficial drivers I found on web.

When I connect my device, it first appears 'Other device' (label is CTVision7) and it's marked as unknown. I tried to install drivers (Google) for it, but windows said that they aren't suitable for my device, as it's not able to find them in specified directory.
After these attempts I tried unofficial drivers. Their installation worked and now my device appears as Android phone, what seems to be good.

But when I run `adb devices` or launch application in eclipse, there's no available device.

I have turned USB debugging on, so it should work.

Am I missing some step to make my device available for debugging, or are my drivers wrong? Is there any way to get drivers which surely work?

Comment: I'd suggest to give Koushik's [Universal Android USB Driver](http://adbdriver.com/) a try. Works for many devices.

Comment: I tried with same result. Driver is successfuly installed, but adb doesn't see my device.

Comment: Do you get the notification on the tablet to say that USB debugging is connected?

Comment: Yes, I do. I also tried to connect Samsung Galaxy Tab (which uses different connector) and it worked with Koushik's drivers. Can I get older version of adb and whole SDK somewhere?

Comment: which adb version are you using right now ? Try adb version 1.0.31.

Comment: And where can I download older versions? I was looking a bit for them on android web and didn't found.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this universal ADB driver](https://plus.google.com/103583939320326217147/posts/BQ5iYJEaaEH).

Comment: Hi, just FYI, since Google+ is not available anymore, the file cannot be downloaded anymore. It'll be appreciated if you could find another source and fix it. Thanks.